# Use Selected Options Value in For Loop

Tags: javascript, css

Good afternoon.

I am trying to use the selected value in the options box in a for loop.

The theory being that if the user selects 3, for example, Javascript will populate 3 boxes with a fruit from the array.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I have enclosed Codepen link too.

```
function changeText(){
    var e = document.getElementById('selectbox');
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    for (var i=0; i<=strUser; i++) {
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = randomFruit + strUser;
    }

}
```

http://codepen.io/jameswinfield/pen/aNWRKm

Comment: You cant use the same id multiple times. You should probably be using a class. Do you want each box to have the same one fruit or would you like each box to have N different fruits?

Comment: I did try changing it to getElementsByClassName but that wasn't working at all.  Yes I do want a different fruit for each box.

Comment: You have to change the boldStuff elements from `id="boldStuff"` to `class="boldStuff"` and you will have to loop over the results of getElementsByClassName because it returns an array of multiple elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID element should be unique to the entire dom. You are using it multiple times for `boldStuff`. If you would like to be able to grab them like that you should use a class.

Here is a version that should do what you want: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzmGLP?editors=0010

Keep in mind that sets the value to every box, even the hidden ones. You will have to get a new random fruit per box or they will all have the same fruit.

I changed all `id="boldStuff"` to `class="boldStuff"`,

grabbed all boldStuffs
    var boldStuffs = document.getElementsByClassName('boldStuff');

and looped over every boldStuff

```
for (var i = 0; i < boldStuffs.length; i += 1) {  
    //And set the value of each boldStuff to a new random fruit.  
    boldStuffs[i].innerHTML = getRandomItem(fruitsArray);  
}
```

The following line also only runs once so no matter how many boxes there are they will all have the same fruit (because randomFruit is never changed)

```
var randomFruit = fruitsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * fruitsArray.length)];
```

You can use a function to grab a random fruit instead, something like this:

```
function getRandomItem(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
```

Then use `getRandomItem(fruitsArray);` to get a random fruit.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it is very much appreciated - I wasn't doing too bad for a JS beginner!

Comment: No problem and no, not at all :) I think most beginners get tripped up on those same points.